# How to interact w/Microsoft Graph API using ADAL.NET and v1

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've successfully written an API that can access a downstream API (using v1 ADAL.NET), so, I have some codes for that.. (the clients were based on AutoRest)

Furthermore, I've successfully gotten a [sample Microsoft Graph web app](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample) running (but, it's coded for v2 and MSAL)

Does anyone have an example of an API accessing a downstream API (i.e. Microsoft Graph). While I can successfully get my access token, when I go to make the call I only get a `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException`:

```
InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Access token validation failure.
```

Sample access token:

```
Header:
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "x5t": "[removed]",
  "kid": "[removed]"
}
Payload:
{
  "aud": "https://graph.windows.net",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/[removed]/",
  "iat": "1533754778",
  "nbf": "1533754778",
  "exp": "1533758925",
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "[removed]",
  "amr": "wia",
  "appid": "[removed]",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "e_exp": "263047",
  "family_name": "My Last Name",
  "given_name": "My Name",
  "ipaddr": "[removed]",
  "name": "My Name My Last Name",
  "oid": "[removed]-7593-4755-1234-bbbb1234aaaa",
  "onprem_sid": "[removed]",
  "puid": "[removed]",
  "scp": "Directory.Read.All Mail.Send User.Read",
  "sub": "[removed]",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "[removed]",
  "unique_name": "me@[removed].com",
  "upn": "me@[removed].com",
  "uti": "[removed]",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

## --- UPDATE ---

Maybe [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) is it? Downloading...

## --- SOLVED ---

I was using the wrong resource uri. See my answer below for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the key things I've learned about interacting with Microsoft Graph API:

- Yes, you CAN use the new client api NuGet from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) with v1 and v2 app registrations
- An example of the `GraphServiceClient` client in use is found [at this QuickStart](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) but it goes against v2 using MSAL
- Borrow code from [this sample project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) to do v1 (ADAL.NET) interactions with traditional app registrations in the portal
- Where I went wrong: *somewhere along the way, I thought the resourceUri I was supposed to use was `https://graph.windows.net`*, but it's really just: `https://graph.microsoft.com`

Comment: Correct. `graph.windows.net` is the Azure Active Directory Graph (i.e. AAD only), not the Microsoft Graph (`graph.microsoft.com) which covers many services (including AAD).